# Opengl: low fps when using texture

Tags: opengl, textures, render, texture-mapping, texture2d

After setting the texture there is 20fps before aplying the texture it was 300fps

My Code:

```
void LoadTEX()
{
  GLuint    texture;  
  HBITMAP   GLtex;
  BITMAP    tex;
  byte      Texture=TEX;

  glGenTextures(sizeof(Texture), &texture);
  GLtex= (HBITMAP)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL),MAKEINTRESOURCE(Texture), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);

  GetObject(GLtex,sizeof(tex), &tex);
  glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT,4);           
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  glTexEnvf( GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST );
  glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );     
  gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, tex.bmWidth, tex.bmHeight, GL_RGB,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tex.bmBits);
  DeleteObject(GLtex);  
}
```

as you can see I load the texture from my resourcs file. I call `LoadTEX()` in my main WINAPI loop.

The second problem is that the texture is a bit transparent so it takes the color from the face behind and mixes it with itself. Why?

Comment: http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#gluBuild2DMipmaps <- gluBuild2DMipmaps is quite old

Comment: How can I use it? I have tried: `glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );` then `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` and finaly:`glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` code compiles but no window is shown.

Comment: glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) is just for fixed pipeline rendering afaik and not needed until you want texture mapping on something your drawing and aren't using shaders. You need to first send the texture data to OpenGL using glTexImage2D, then call glGenerateMipmap. Make sure you have an appropriate mipmapping filter set (there's also GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR). You might want to take a look at anisotropic filtering too.

Answer (score 3):

> I call LoadTEX() in my main WINAPI loop.

I'm assuming this means that you call this once per frame, in which case this is the reason for your performance drop. You should load the texture once before your loop, and then draw it each frame.

> The second problem is that the texture is a bit transparent so it takes the color from the face behind and mixes it with itself

Without seeing your code for rendering the texture this is hard to say why. Disable blending with glDisable(GL_BLEND) and your texture will no longer be transparent.